# Java insert image into database code not working

Tags: java, runtime-error, execution, classnotfoundexception

[image: As you can see that im in the current path of executing the java file.]

As you can see that I am in the current path of executing the java file.
When I compile the program I am getting a class file successfully.
but wen I run it I m unable to execute that program as I am getting the error in the image telling that there's no such class in that path available..

```
C:\Users\admin>javac insertImg.java

C:\Users\admin>java insertImg
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: insertImg
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: insertImg
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: insertImg.  Program will exit.

C:\Users\admin>
```

---

### And this is my java code for inserting image into database.....

insertImg.java:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class insertImg{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Insert Image Example!");
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "hibernatetutorial";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            File imgfile = new File("images.jpg");
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);

            PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("insert into Image values(?,?,?)");
            pre.setInt(1,5);
            pre.setString(2,"Durga");
            pre.setBinaryStream(3,fin,(int)imgfile.length());
            pre.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Inserting Successfully!");

            pre.close();
            con.close();  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code how you load the image...

Comment: murali and stefan i have posted the code above...can you identify some problems in my code...if so pls suggest...

Comment: Is the class file being generated moved to some other directory? If so, then you need to do `java insertImg` in that directory or set the classpath to include that folder.

Comment: try javac -d insertImg.java

Answer (score 0):

Does insertImg.java have a class insertImg (note case sensitivity), that has a public `main` function?

Comment: yeah everything seems to be perfect...but i dont recognize wat is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I see You got the code from roseIndia it is working for me without any hitch. however its still weird from whatever your showing ..my suggestion is to use an IDE like eclipse

you can always try the following steps

1) Create a table in your Mysql database to suit the above code

```
CREATE TABLE IMAGE
(
 IMG_ID    INT,
 IMG_NAME  VARCHAR2(100),
 IMG       BLOB
)
```

2) Create a new java project in eclipse and create a new class insertImg and paste the code   there. please make sure your image file path is same as where your image is and run it.   Its working fine

Comment: i hav created the same table and even i used the mysql connector to support jdbc connection..still i hav the same problem...i will follow your second step and get back to you....

Comment: it works fine in eclipse ide....but for what reason the same program is not working in non ide based environment....

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ive tried with Oracle database had to add the -classpath ojdbc.jar and it worked from the console also as you can see in the image 
and my image file that i loaded in the database is in D:\ so its is not in the above screenshot

hope this helps

Comment: you are getting a classnot found exception but i m getting a no class definition found exception....i even tried it by adding all the necessary jar files like ojdbc and mysql connector.jar file...but there seems to be something else which throws that error...and where is ur image file...there is nothing i can see there...

Comment: I couldnt reconstruct your error but it has worked for me from the console also

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple classpath error. The `CLASSPATH` environment variable allows Java to know where to look for classes.

Unfortunately, Java is not intelligent enough to know that it needs to look for classes in the local directory. To resolve this issue, all you have to do is execute one of the following statements depending on whether you are using windows or Linux/Unix:

For Windows:

```
set CLASSPATH=.;%CLASSPATH%
```

For Linux:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: or specify the `-cp` parameter.